# ASP.NET MVC Extension Methods Hint Shows The Extended Type In Param List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

The hint for extension methods on a normal class file and the one shown on my aspx page do not match.

The hint shown on the aspx page also shows the type that is being extended. Its annoying.

[Imaget http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/8208/29713561.jpg](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/8208/29713561.jpg)

Can anybody tell me what wrong with my Visual Studio? I am using VS 2008 am I missing any fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your Visual Studio, that's just how extension methods are shown.  The object (in your case the HtmlHelper object) is actually a parameter of the extension method, which is why you see it that way.

Comment: Then why does it have the this keyword in front of it?

Comment: Because that's how you define an extension method, by using the "this" keyword in the first param and declaring the method as static.

Comment: I mean normally the param with the this keyword is the object that you are extending and it should not come up in the Hint.

Anyways this only happens with the MVC Futures assembly.